# Python access derived class attributes in parent constructor

Tags: python

I've a class structure like

```
class Parent:
   value_type = (object,)
   def __init__(self, value):
      if not isinstance(value, value_type):
          raise ValueError
      self.value = value

class Derived(Parent):
    value_type = (str,)
```

When I create an instance variable of derived class as

```
d = Derived(555)
```

It doesn't raises any error. (The behaviour I need is that it should raise an error in this case as 555 is not a `str`)

Is there any way to make the parent class constructor use the derived class attribute `value_type` instead of it's own class attribute?

I know passing value_type as a parameter to `__init__` function is a solution, but the `value_type` should be same throughout the class, so I don't want to redundantly add same `value_type` field everytime to initialize a derived class instance.

Comment: This very much _does_ raise an error, namely `NameError: name 'value_type' is not defined`.

Comment: Note you should probably raise a `TypeError`, and ideally with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value_type` used in `Parent` is always the value of `value_type` in the scope, which is whatever you assigned `value_type` to be in the global scope.

To fix this, use `self.value_type` to get the `value_type` assigned to the created instance:

```
def __init__(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, self.value_type):
        raise TypeError
    self.value = value
```